# Data model for blog application with Firebase / Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

We have a requirement to create an blog application where user's can write blogs like in [medium.com](http://medium.com) or wordpress in general.

User can add text and images as and when they want.

Thought of using Angular for UI and Firebase/Firestore as database service.

Blogs can be a collection of its own where each blog will be a document under blogs.

Was wondering how to store the entire blog content which is mix of text and images in any random fashion.

Comment: Also doing the same right now, with Vue instead of Angular but it shouldnt matter, for now i have a Tag system like every post has certain tags and further operations in the frontend work with those, but im still curious how to properly store the images and im looking forward to answers on your post

Comment: @Badgy How easy is it learn Vue ? Coming from Javascript and Angular background ? Been thinking to give it a try but not getting enough time for it.

Comment: i used Angular but not React, but the common opinion i often hear is that vue takes the best of both and combines it, just read some articles, its defenetly less complex than Angular which makes it for myself a more fun experience since there are many ways, with Nuxt  you also have easy SSR avaliable which i also use right now since its essential for SEO specially in a blog page. But just read some articles in the internet about the topic of which framework, all have advantages and disadvantages. But like 98%+ jobs do not use vue so if you wanna work in the near future angular may

Comment: benefit you more because you get more ready for a job, but vue is rising so its also not bad to go for it and learn it, its a fairly new one

Comment: @Badgy Were you able to achieve your task? Even I am looking for Nuxt based solution for blog using Firebase. Any Lead will be helpful rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @just10minutes Hey, I stored the Images on a CDN like Cloudinary, but Firebase Storage is also fine. On Creation of the Post I uploaded the images and stored the link to the image inside the document for example as title image or inside the actual blog content as an img tag or json tag depends on how you store your content and what editor you implement. If you have questions just @ me

Comment: @Badgy I have invited you for a chat. Please respond there if possible.

Comment: I have developed a blog using angular and Firestore. The blog data can be stored as collections and images can be stored in firebase storage. Otherwise, you can convert image to Base64 and save it within the collection itself.